# What binary relation is neither symmetric, nor asymmetric nor antisymmetric?

Tags: relations

I thought it was the relation $\varnothing$, but the answer in the textbook I am using does not mention this as a possible answer. I don't understand why it can't be the answer. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a relation $R$ to be symmetric, **every** ordered pair $(a,b)$ in $R$ will also have $(b,a)\in R$.

For a relation to be asymmetric, **every** ordered pair $(a,b)\in R$ *does not* have $(b,a)\in R$.

For a relation to be antisymmetric, if *both* $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in $R$ then $a=b$.

So we want $R$ such that for some $a\neq b$, $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are both in $R$ this makes sure $R$ is neither asymmetric nor antisymmetric; but at the same time we want some $(c,d)\in R$ such that $(d,c)\notin R$, as this will ensure that $R$ is not symmetric.

In either case, we need *witnesses* in $R$ to prove that it is not symmetric or asymmetric. Therefore it cannot be empty.

---

I will leave the grueling details of writing down such $R$ for you.

Comment: instead of the word "witnesses" should it be "instances" or "cases"?

Comment: No, the term "witness" is standard here. $0$ is a witness to the fact that $\{0\}$ is non-empty.

Answer (score 7):

$\varnothing$ is the (unique) example of a relation that is symmetric, asymmetric and antisymmetric (so the opposite of what you are looking for).

E.g. a relation $R$ is not symmetric if an ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ exist with $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ and $\langle b,a\rangle\notin R$.

This is evidently not true for $R=\varnothing$ (it contains no ordered pairs) so we conclude that $\varnothing$ is symmetric.

Likewise it can be shown that $\varnothing$ is asymmetric and antisymmetric.

The implications involved are *vacuously true*.

Answer (score 5):

In the empty relation, it is impossible for $xRy$, so that whenever $xRy$ it is true that $yRx$ - you have a statement about elements of the empty set, and there aren't any such elements to make the statement false.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

S = {a,b,c}

R = { (a,b), (a,c), (c,a) }

*Then:*

1. R is not symmetric, because aRb is true, but bRa is false.

2. R is not asymmetric, because aRc and cRa.

3. R is not antisymmetric, because aRc and cRa, yet a<>c.